# Can the Samba security setting `wide links` be bypassed using a race condition?

Tags: security, samba

Apache has options `FollowSymLinks` and `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`.  However, they "should not be considered a security restriction, since symlink testing is subject to race conditions that make it circumventable."  Compare this with Samba:

Samba has an option called `wide links` :

> Note: Turning this parameter on when UNIX extensions are enabled will allow UNIX clients to create symbolic links on the share that can point to files or directories outside restricted path exported by the share definition. This can cause access to areas outside of the share. Due to this problem, this parameter will be automatically disabled (with a message in the log file) if the `unix extensions` option is on.
>
> See the parameter `allow insecure wide links` if you wish to change this coupling between the two parameters.

Can the Samba option be bypassed via a race condition?

If not, how is Samba able to prevent the race condition?  E.g. what sequence of operations can be used to prevent the race condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly *was* vulnerable.  See [CVE-2017-2619](https://www.samba.org/samba/security/CVE-2017-2619.html).

The [patch](https://www.samba.org/samba/ftp/patches/security/samba-4.6.0-CVE-2017-2619.patch) for this bug includes a new function, called `open_dir_safely()`.  It uses `chdir()` to enter the directory that contains the file to be opened.

I guess this means you can use `getcwd()`, to check you are still inside the Samba shared directory.  At least that could work quite nicely on Linux, because it has an efficient system call for `getcwd()`.  I have not confirmed exactly what Samba does after `chdir()`.

This is not great if your process has multiple threads, because `chdir()` affects the whole process :-).  Linux-specific programs could instead use `open()` with the `O_PATH` flag, and then use `readlink()` on the open file descriptor under `/proc/self/fd/`.

The above can provide assurance about the directory that contains the file.  To ensure the *file* name is not resolved as a link when you pass it to `open()`, you can use the `O_NOFOLLOW` flag.  If it *is* a symlink, `open()` will return `ELOOP`.  Then you may `readlink()` the file and resolve the symlink yourself.  This would involve repeating the procedure from the start :-).

If you have to repeat the procedure "too many" times, then you can return failure (`ELOOP` again).  (And the same if you have to retry too many times because someone is playing silly beggars and repeatedly changing the file between `open(... O_NOFOLLOW)` and `readlink()`).

On a non-Linux OS, you might not have a very efficient `getcwd()`.  If you have `O_PATH`, then you can avoid `getcwd()` by iterating through *every* segment of the path, using `O_PATH` + `O_NOFOLLOW` and manually resolving links.

In future, this problem might be addressed by some specific flag like [AT_PATH_BENEATH or O_BENEATH](https://lwn.net/Articles/767547/).